# Mongodb update duplicate array value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am getting in an array of data and then want to insert that into my mongodb. I want to overwrite any duplicate values with the new one (on Im uploading) and if no duplicates just add it onto the current array.

I currently have:

```
db.cases.updateOne(
    { companyID: 218 },
    {
      $addToSet: {
        cases: [AN ARRAY OF CASES]
      },
      $currentDate: { lastModified: true }
    })
```

The collection has multiple companies and each has an array of cases - see image below :

[image]

The other thing that doesn't seem to work is that the **currentDate** doesn't seem to change whenever I update the cases, not sure if thats the way I have written the query?

Thank you.

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#value-to-add-is-an-array) addresses adding an array with `$addToSet`

Comment: @MarkMeyer the only issue is that $addToSet does nothing to the array if a duplicate exists, but i want to update that duplicate to be the newest incase values have changed.

Comment: if the values have changed it's no longer a duplicate. Duplicate objects need to match exactly. "...you cannot specify that MongoDB compare only a subset of the fields in the document to determine whether the document is a duplicate of an existing array element."

Comment: @MarkMeyer ah thanks that makes sense. So there is not a way of looping through and seeing if the cases I want to add contains one with a id 299  and if so I must overwrite that one? The problem with not doing it, is that I now have 2 versions of the case with id 299 and it makes the stats Im working out incorrect

Comment: It sounds like you might be better off with `update` (or similar) and setting [`upsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-upsert) to true. This will update existing documents or create them if they don't exist.

Comment: @MarkMeyer thank you will look into that

Answer (score 0):

You can use $addToSet (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) with $[] (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to accomplish this.

I scripted an example in Node.js to show you what I mean:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

async function main() {
    /**
     * Connection URI. Update <username>, <password>, and <your-cluster-url> to reflect your cluster.
     */
    const uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<your-cluster-url>?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

    /**
     * The Mongo Client you will use to interact with your database
     */
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

    try {
        // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
        await client.connect();

        // Make the appropriate DB calls
        await updateArray(client, 'id1')


    } finally {
        // Close the connection to the MongoDB cluster
        await client.close();
    }
}

main().catch(console.error);

async function updateArray(client, id) {
    const docId = "299";
    const mynewdoc = {
        id: docId,
        priority: 5,
        casenumber: 40,
        new: "field"
    }
    const result = await client.db("NameOfYourDb").collection("NameOfYourCollection").updateOne(
        { _id: id },
        {
            $set: {
                "cases.$[element]": mynewdoc
            }
        },
        {
            arrayFilters: [{ "element.id": docId }]
        }
    )

    if (result) {
        console.log(result);
    } else {
        console.log(`Not found '${id}'`);
    }

    const result2 = await client.db("NameOfYourDb").collection("NameOfYourCollection").updateOne(
        { _id: id },
        {
            $addToSet: {
                "cases": mynewdoc
            }
        }
    )

    if (result2) {
        console.log(result2);
    } else {
        console.log(`Not found '${id}'`);
    }

}
```

See https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs-mongodb--how-to-get-connected-to-your-database for an explanation of how the Node.js code is structured.

Comment: I thought of a new solution but wondered if its possible - Could I just add it all to the array and then once in, I loop through the array and fin all that have the same casenumber and then delete the first (oldest) occurrence of that? I have the code to add to the array, its just looking for the duplicate casenumber and deleting oldest.

Comment: That sounds like it would work.  Performance wise - it could take a while to iterate over every element in an array to look for duplicates later in the array.

Comment: I have added an answer that works but not exactly to what I need - do you have any ideas on how to get it save into a specific document?

Comment: I think what you need to do is ensure that each stage retains all of the fields from the previous stage.  Then you'll need to group them at the end by companyId to get the original documents.

Answer (score 0):

So I have figured a hack around but it is not exactly what I wanted - maybe someone can use this and expand upon it to make it work better:

```
db.cases.aggregate(
    { $match: { 'companyID': 218 }},
    { $unwind: '$cases' }, 
    { $group: { "_id": "$cases.casenumber", cases: {$push:'$cases'}, "count": { $sum:1 }}},
    { $match: { "count": { "$gt": 1 }}}
    { $project: { "cases": { $slice: [ "$cases", -1, { $subtract: [ { $size: "$cases" }, 1 ]}] }}},
    { $project: { "cases": { $arrayElemAt: ['$cases', 0] }}},
    { $group: { _id: 1, cases: {$push:'$cases' }}},
    { $out: 'cases' }
)
```

The only problem is that using out overwrites the cases document so I need to figure out a way to write it to the cases array inside of the company id (218)

Hopefully this can help someone though.

Thanks.